# Cannot connect to WiFi VirtualBox Ubuntu 12.04 on MacBook Pro

Tags: 12.04, wireless, virtualbox, macbook

I run two VMs on a MacBook Pro:  Windows7 and Ubuntu 12.04.  Both can connect to LANs via hardwired connections; Windows 7 connects also connects automatically to any authorized WiFi network.  Ubuntu 12.04 cannot find a WiFi network.  iwconfig reports "no wireless extensions."  VirtualBox's Devices/Network Adapters' bridged option, however, recognizes the MacBook's Airport WiFi adapter.  Despite hours of reading and searching and experimentation, I'm making no progress.  Does anyone have any suggestions???

Comment: Is then network connection in *bridged* mode functional? Virtual Box establishes networking to the host with a virtual network adapter, independent of hardware.

Comment: Yes, bridged mode works fine with a wired connection.